# Regex pattern to match string that's not followed by a colon

Tags: regex, pcre

Using regex, I'm trying to match any string of characters that meets the following conditions (in the order displayed):

- Contains a dollar sign `$`; then
- at least one letter `[a-zA-Z]`; then
- zero or more letters, numbers, underscores, periods (dots), opening brackets, and/or closing brackets `[a-zA-Z0-9_.\[\]]*`; then
- one pipe character `|`; then
- one at sign `@`; then
- at least one letter `[a-zA-Z]`; then
- zero or more letters, numbers, and/or underscores `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`; then
- zero colons `:`

In other words, if a colon is found at the end of the string, then it should **not** count as a match.

Here are some examples of valid matches:

```
$tmp1|@hello
$x2.h|@hi_th3re
Valid match$here|@in_the middle of other characters
```

And here are some examples of invalid matches:

```
$tmp2|@not_a_match:"because there is a colon"
$c.4a|@also_no_match:
```

Here are some of the patterns I've tried:

```
(\$[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.\[\]]*)(\|@)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?!.[:]))
(\$[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.\[\]]+)?(\|@)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?![:]))
(\$[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.\[\]]+)?(\|@)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)([^:])
```

Comment: You can also try: [`\$\w+[][.\w]*\|@[^\W:]+`](https://regex101.com/r/iC1sH1/1) might not be accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will do what you need

```
\$[A-Za-z]+[\w.\[\]]*[|]@[A-Za-z]+[\w]*+(?!:)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX2uY2/4)**

I am using possessive quantifiers to cut down the backtracking using `[\w]*+`. You can also use atomic groups instead of possessive quantifiers like

```
\$[A-Za-z]+[\w.\[\]]*[|]@[A-Za-z]+(?>[\w]*)(?!:)
```

**NOTE**

> \w => [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: The problem with this one is the string may or may not be at the beggining or end of the line.

Comment: Perfect, but if I add grouping will that affect anything?

Comment: @jerdiggity are you talking about capturing group?in that case you can use it freely

Comment: Of course (I'll also add it to the question). For example, I'll need to retain each matched piece so that everything after `|@` can be moved to the beginning of the string, with an open parenthesis added directly after it, and then everything after `|@` will go after that parenthesis, and then a closing parenthesis will be added after that. e.g. `$tmp1|@hello` would become `hello($tmp1)`

Comment: Excellent, @rock321987. Thanks so much. That worked perfectly. :)

Comment: @jerdiggity glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

I tested your third pattern in Regex 101 and it appears to be working correctly:

```
^.*(\$[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.\[\]]+)?(\|@)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)([^:]).*$
```

The only change I needed to make to the regex to make it work was to add anchors `^` and `$` to the start and end of the regex.  I also allowed for your pattern to occur as a substring in the middle of a larger string.

By the way, you had the following example as a string which should not match:

```
$tmp2|@not_a_match:"because there is a colon"
```

However, even if we remove the colon from this string it will still not match because it contains quotes which are not allowed.

## Regex101

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit with an example of a valid string that's in the middle of others.

Comment: @jerdiggity I updated my answer.  Your third regex was fine, it only needed some slight tuning.